# How to split a commit at the middle of a branch history?

Tags: git, github

Let's imagine I have the following branch:

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E 
                    ^(HEAD, master*)
```

I need to split up the B into H and J:

```
A -- H -- J -- C' -- D' -- E' 
                           ^(HEAD, master*)
' means hash of C, D and E will be updated
```

These ways aren't suitable:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3 #or
git reset --mixed HEAD~3
```

Because the real situation is that the target commit (B) is ~200 commits
earlier than the HEAD of master branch. So I don't want to list them all in interactive mode. There is no problems with remote, because it's just local untracked/topic branch and I want to learn how to do various manipulations the commit history.

What I tried:

```
git checkout B #detached HEAD mode
git reset HEAD^
# here I split B into two logically separated commits H and J
git rebase -i --onto HEAD master #? here I have no idea what to do next

# I also tried this:
git rebase -i HEAD~4 HEAD~2
# but the result is detached mode and no idea what to do next again
```

Any ideas? Please I don't have good git knowledge so it would be great if somebody could explain this step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `git reset HEAD^` in your steps you get you B commit staged on top of A.

You do your splitting, usually by adding files, optionally in interactive mode where you can split the changes to one file into separate commit (see `git add -i`).

When you are done with your splitting and have your J commit, you rebase the rest of the history on top of it:

```
git rebase --onto J B E
```

which means replay commits starting (but excluding) B and to (inclusive) E on top of J.

Comment: Short and effective!) Thank you!)